# Why some of the content cannot be extracted

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need to extract this from the cell
For example:
A1 : abode abcd=1000seconds long=50cm
I need only 1000. With this sequence and this formula I can extract 1000 from the cell.

The formula I use is MID(A1, SEARCH(“=“,A1) + LEN(“=“), SEARCH(“seconds”,A1)-SEARCH(“=“,A1)-LEN(“=“))+0

However when the sequence of cell become:

A1 : long=50cmabode abcd=1000seconds

The 1000 cannot be extracted.

Please help

Comment: Show few more examples, do you specifically need 1000 to extract from the string, will it be always 1000, will it be always a len of 4 characters? what is your excel version.?

Comment: No it will be any numbers not always Len of 4. Excel version is 2016

Comment: So please show few more samples.

Comment: May I know what kind of samples you would like to see?

Comment: like few more examples, of your data

Answer (score 0):

Edit, since OP mentioned they are using Excel 2016, formula changed accordingly

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `D2`

```
=SUBSTITUTE(FILTERXML("<m><b>"&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(B2,"="," ")," ","</b><b>")&"</b></m>","//b[contains(., 'seconds')]"),"seconds","")
```

---

Alternative Approach,

• Formula used in cell `C2`

```
=SUM(IFERROR(--TEXTAFTER(TEXTBEFORE(B2,"seconds"),"=",{1,2}),0))
```

Comment: If the number is 0 it cannot be extracted.

Comment: @zora you have not mentioned earlier that the number can be 0.

Comment: @zora i have updated the formula, using `FILTERXML()` that should work for your version of excel